# View not attached to window manager android crash

Tags: java, android, tabs

There are a lot of similar post to this but I cannot seem to figure it out. This happens in multiple views when I push the back button.  They are views that are not part of my tabbarmanager

Here is the logcat

```
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039): Activity com.myAppusa.TabManager has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40e909c0 that was originally added here
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myAppusa.TabManager has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40e909c0 that was originally added here
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:396)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:372)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:320)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.myAppusa.ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.Gifts(ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.java:240)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.myAppusa.ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.onCreate(ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.java:91)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2015)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.myAppusa.TabGroupActivity.finishFromChild(TabGroupActivity.java:50)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:3785)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.myAppusa.TabGroupActivity.onBackPressed(TabGroupActivity.java:104)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.myAppusa.TabGroupActivity.onKeyUp(TabGroupActivity.java:89)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2692)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2398)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1894)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:302)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1271)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1967)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1402)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2393)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1894)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3633)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-30 17:02:44.657: E/WindowManager(7039):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code for one of the pages that does this when I click back.

```
public class ActivityYourGift extends Activity {
    String terms;
    TextView tv_restaurantRewardsTitle;
    TextView tvGift, tvFrom, tvCaption, tvCompanyName, tvAddress, tvAddress2, tvDealerId, tvTrackingId, tvTerms, tvClose;
    ImageView ivUserImg, ivImageView;
    ImageView ivDealImg;
    String urlImg, user_img;
    public String user_id_restaurant;
    private TextView tvTerms_desc;
    private TextView tvValidUsername;
    private ImageView mbtnGiftMap;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip_code;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_gift_layout);
        tv_restaurantRewardsTitle =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_restaurantRewardsTitle);
        /*set font for view*/
        //setFont();
        Intent in = getIntent();

        terms = in.getStringExtra("terms");
        user_img = in.getStringExtra("user_img");
        String caption = in.getStringExtra("caption");



        tvGift.setText(title);
        tvFrom.setText(name + " sent you this gift!");
        if (caption.length() == 0){
            tvCaption.setText("Test");
        }else{
            tvCaption.setText(caption);
        }
        tvTerms_desc.setText(terms);
        tvValidUsername.setText("Valid for " + name);
        tvDealerId.setText("");
        tvTrackingId.setText("Tracking: " + voucher);


        urlImg = "http://myApp.com";



        if(ivDealImg!=null){
            //new ImageDownloaderTask(mIvLogo).execute(urlImg+logo);
            int loader = R.drawable.loader;
            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
            imgLoader.DisplayImage(urlImg+deal_img, loader, ivDealImg, true);

        }

        if(ActivityLogin.has_restaurant=="no" && Double.parseDouble(distance) < 0.1){
            showAlertDialogClaimRestaurant(getParent(), "Additional Rewards!", "Would you like to subscribe to this restaurants loyalty reward program for additional deals and savings?", true);
        }

        if(ivUserImg!=null){
            //new ImageDownloaderTask(mIvLogo).execute(urlImg+logo);
            int loader = R.drawable.loader;
            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
            imgLoader.DisplayImage(urlImg+user_img, loader, ivUserImg, false);
        }


        mbtnGiftMap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_map_gift);
        mbtnGiftMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address + "+" + city + "+" + state));
                startActivity(intent);
                /*Intent mapintent = new Intent(ActivityYourGift.this, RestaurantMap.class);

                mapintent.putExtra("zipCode", zip_code);
                mapintent.putExtra("CityInfo", city);
                mapintent.putExtra("AddressInfo", address);
                Log.d("zipcode and city and address in gift", zip_code + city + address);

                startActivity(mapintent);*/
            }
        });
        tvAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address + "+" + city + "+" + state));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
//      
        ivUserImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                setContentView(R.layout.image_view);
                ivImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_tab_icon);
                /*tvClose = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.close);
                tvClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        setContentView(R.layout.your_gift_layout);

                    }
                });*/
                if(ivImageView!=null){
                    //new ImageDownloaderTask(mIvLogo).execute(urlImg+logo);
                    int loader = R.drawable.loader;
                    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                    imgLoader.DisplayImage(urlImg+user_img, loader, ivImageView, true);
                }
            }


        });

    }

    /* dialog check member */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialogClaimRestaurant(Context context, String title,
            String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)
            alertDialog
                    .setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }

        });

        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ClaimRestaurant();



            }

        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void ClaimRestaurant() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = ActivityLogin.webServiceURL;
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //NO RESPONSE

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        //Log.i("Error.Response", error.getMessage());

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", ActivityLogin.token);
                params.put("mode", "claimRestaurant");
                params.put("user_id", ActivityLogin.id);
                params.put("user_id_restaurant", user_id_restaurant);
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }

    /* set font for view */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setFont() {

        String fontPathTitle = "fonts/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF";       

        Typeface tfTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPathTitle);        

        tv_restaurantRewardsTitle.setTypeface(tfTitle); 
    }
    /*alert to exit*/
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialogExit(Context context, String title,
            String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();


        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)

            alertDialog
                    .setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);


        alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }

        });

        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }

        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            ActivityYourGift.this.finish();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertTerms(Context context, String title,
            String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog
                    .setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);


        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }

        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Here is ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.java

```
    package com.myAppusa;

/* IMPORTS REMOVED */

public class ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {
    static String tab;
    Button btn_gfits, btn_rewards;
    ImageView iv_downLeft, iv_downRight;
    LinearLayout layout_gfits, layout_rewards;
    TextView tv_persionalRewardGiftTitle;
    ListView listReward, listGift;
    RewardsAdapter rewardsadapter;
    GiftsAdapter giftsadapter;
    ArrayList<Gifts> arraylistGifts = new ArrayList<Gifts>();
    ArrayList<Rewards> arrayRewards = new ArrayList<Rewards>();
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal_reward_gifts);

        /* Init view */
        btn_gfits = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gifts);
        btn_rewards = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_rewards);

        iv_downLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_dropLeft);
        iv_downRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_dropRight);

        layout_gfits = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_gfits);
        layout_rewards = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_rewards);
        tv_persionalRewardGiftTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_persionalRewardGiftTitle);

        /* set onclick Button */
        btn_gfits.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_rewards.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(tab=="rewards"){
            loadRewards();
        }else{
            Gifts();
        }
        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        giftsadapter = new GiftsAdapter(this, R.layout.persional_gifts_items, arraylistGifts);
        rewardsadapter = new RewardsAdapter(this, R.layout.persional_rewards_items, arrayRewards);
        listGift = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_gfits);
        listReward = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_rewards);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        //listReward.setAdapter(rewardsadapter);
        listGift.setAdapter(giftsadapter);
        listReward.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Rewards rewards = arrayRewards.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(),
                        ActivityRestaurantRewards.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
                intent.putExtra("company_name_rewards", rewards.getCompany_name());


                intent.putExtra("name", rewards.getName());
                intent.putExtra("terms", rewards.getTerms());
                intent.putExtra("reward", rewards.getReward());

                parentActivity.startChildActivity("ActivityRestaurantRewards", intent);
            }
        });
        listGift.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Gifts gifts = arraylistGifts.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), ActivityYourGift.class);
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
                intent.putExtra("company_name", gifts.getCompany_name());
                intent.putExtra("deal_img", gifts.getDealImg());
                intent.putExtra("address", gifts.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("city", gifts.getCity());
                intent.putExtra("state", gifts.getState());
                intent.putExtra("zip_code", gifts.getZipCode());

                intent.putExtra("name", gifts.getName());
                intent.putExtra("voucher", gifts.getVoucher());
                intent.putExtra("terms", gifts.getTerms());
                intent.putExtra("title", gifts.getTitle());

                intent.putExtra("user_img", gifts.getUserImg());
                intent.putExtra("caption", gifts.getCaption());

                intent.putExtra("distance", gifts.getDistance());
                intent.putExtra("user_id", gifts.getUserId());

                parentActivity.startChildActivity("ActivityYourGift", intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void Reward() {
        tab="rewards";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = ActivityLogin.webServiceURL;
        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "", "Loading...");
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("rewards");
                            arrayRewards = new ArrayList<Rewards>();
                            final String error = json.getString("error");
                            if (error.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Rewards rew = new Rewards();
                                    rew.setCompany_name(item
                                            .optString("company_name"));
                                    rew.setExpiration("Expires "
                                            + item.optString("expiration"));
                                    rew.setImg(item.optString("img"));
                                    rew.setVoucher(item.optString("voucher"));
                                    rew.setPercent(item.optString("percent"));
                                    rew.setAddress(item
                                            .optString("street_address"));
                                    rew.setCity(item.optString("city"));
                                    rew.setState(item.optString("state"));
                                    rew.setZip_code(item.optString("zip_code"));
                                    rew.setName(item.optString("name"));
                                    rew.setTerms(item.optString("terms"));
                                    rew.setReward(item.optString("reward"));
                                    arrayRewards.add(rew);
                                }

                                rewardsadapter = new RewardsAdapter(
                                        ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.this,
                                        R.layout.persional_rewards_items,
                                        arrayRewards);
                                // Reward();
                                listReward.setAdapter(rewardsadapter);
                            } else {
                                alert.showAlertDialog(getParent(),
                                        "myApp alert!", error, false);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        rewardsadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        //Log.i("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", ActivityLogin.token);
                params.put("mode", "getRewards");
                params.put("user_id", ActivityLogin.id);
                params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(ActivityLogin.latitude));
                params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(ActivityLogin.longitude));
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);

    }

    private void Gifts() {
        /* dialog */
        tab="gifts";
        String test = getParent().toString();
        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "", "Loading...");
        pdialog.setCancelable(true);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = ActivityLogin.webServiceURL;
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("rewards");
                            ActivityLogin.has_restaurant = json.getString("has_restaurant");
                            arraylistGifts = new ArrayList<Gifts>();
                            final String error = json.getString("error");
                            if (error.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Gifts gif = new Gifts();
                                    gif.setCompany_name(item.optString("company_name"));
                                    gif.setExpiration("Expires " + item.optString("expiration"));
                                    gif.setDeal_img(item.optString("deal_img"));
                                    gif.setTitle(item.optString("title"));
                                    gif.setName(item.optString("name"));
                                    gif.setUserImg(item.optString("user_img"));
                                    gif.setCaption(item.optString("caption"));
                                    gif.setTerms(item.optString("terms"));
                                    gif.setAddress(item.optString("street_address") + " " + item.optString("street_address2"));
                                    gif.setCity(item.optString("city"));
                                    gif.setState(item.optString("state"));
                                    gif.setZipCode(item.optString("zip_code"));
                                    gif.setVoucher(item.optString("voucher"));
                                    gif.setDistance(item.optString("distance"));
                                    gif.setUserId(item.optString("user_id"));
                                    arraylistGifts.add(gif);

                                }

                                giftsadapter = new GiftsAdapter(
                                        ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.this,
                                        R.layout.persional_gifts_items,
                                        arraylistGifts);
                                // Gifts();
                                listGift.setAdapter(giftsadapter);

                                if(ActivityLogin.firstLogin){

                                    listGift.performItemClick(listGift.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, listGift.getAdapter().getItemId(0));
                                }
                            } else {
                                alert.showAlertDialog(getParent(),
                                        "myApp alert!", error, false);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        giftsadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // error
                        //Log.i("Error.Response", error.getMessage());
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token", ActivityLogin.token);
                params.put("mode", "getGifts");
                params.put("user_id", ActivityLogin.id);
                params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(ActivityLogin.latitude));
                params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(ActivityLogin.longitude));
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_gifts: {

            /* visible or invisible layout Rewards and gifts */
            layout_gfits.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_rewards.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            /* visible or invisible Image down Rewards and gifts */
            iv_downLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_downRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            /* Change background Button tab Rewards and gifts */
            btn_gfits
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.color.activity_bar_button_selected);
            btn_rewards
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.color.activity_bar_button_unselected);

            /* Change TextColor Button tab Rewards and gifts */
            btn_gfits.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            btn_rewards.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#15bcdd"));

            // load when click
            Gifts();

        }
            break;

        case R.id.btn_rewards: {

            loadRewards();

        }
            break;
        /*
         * case R.id.iv_backScreenPersonalRewardGift:{
         * showAlertDialogExit(ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.this,
         * "myApp alert!", "Do you want to exit myApp ?", false); }break;
         */
        }
    }
    private void loadRewards(){
        tab="rewards";
        /* visible or invisible layout Rewards and gifts */
        layout_rewards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout_gfits.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        /* visible or invisible Image down Rewards and gifts */
        iv_downLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        iv_downRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        /* Change background Button tab Rewards and gifts */
        btn_rewards
                .setBackgroundResource(R.color.activity_bar_button_selected);
        btn_gfits
                .setBackgroundResource(R.color.activity_bar_button_unselected);

        /* Change TextColor Button tab Rewards and gifts */
        btn_rewards.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        btn_gfits.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#15bcdd"));

        // load when click

        Reward();


    }
    /* set font for view */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setFont() {
        // Font path
        String fontPathTitle = "fonts/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF";
        String fontPathButton = "fonts/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf";
        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tfTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPathTitle);
        Typeface tfButton = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                fontPathButton);
        // Applying font
        tv_persionalRewardGiftTitle.setTypeface(tfTitle);
        btn_rewards.setTypeface(tfButton);
        btn_gfits.setTypeface(tfButton);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialogExit(Context context, String title,
            String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog
                    .setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }

        });

        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }

        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent().getParent();
            //tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(4);
            tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("tab1");
            //return false;
        }

        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am new to android so don't assume I know anything. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post code for ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits.java

Comment: I only had so many characters so I removed the imports.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a couple hours but I finally figured it out. I have a TabManager.java file that handles the tab bar.  So I was looking in the wrong place the entire time. The activities go TabGroupActivity > ActivityPersonalRewardsGfits > ActivityYourGift

So when the back button was pressed it was triggering the `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` function in TabGroupActivity where the `finish();` method was being called (someone snuck that in there). This is what caused the problem. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) helped me out immensely in solving the problem.